# How to unintall Anaconda environments after uninstalling Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, package, uninstallation

I recently uninstalled Anaconda.  After that, I found the folders .keras, .jupyter, .matplotlib and a few others under my users folder.  So, it looks like Anaconda left a lot of packages behind.  How can I uninstall these and whatever other folders that were left behind by Anaconda?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to re-install conda to run these commands but it has commands to remove itself just run these commands in Anaconda prompt (or a linux/MacOS Terminal)

```
conda install anaconda-clean
```

This is the package used to wipe it off of your machine

```
anaconda-clean
```

Run the package itself, however this will ask you about each one to just clear them all on its own, you may end up having to re-install something you need use:

```
anaconda-clean --yes
```

Extra info: a backup is made by both in your home directory and other directories in .anaconda_backup/anaconda-clean

You don't note your OS so if you are on Linux/MacOS to clear it off of your bash terminal use:

```
export PATH="<Directory>/<User>/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"
```

Don't forget to replace what is between <> with your own directory, this is formatted off of where it is normally installed.

For more information visit the official documentation here [https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/#:~:text=Use%20simple%20remove%20to%20uninstall,or%20your%20version%20of%20Python](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/uninstall/#:%7E:text=Use%20simple%20remove%20to%20uninstall,or%20your%20version%20of%20Python).

Comment: Well, i reinstalled anaconda and installed anaconda-clean.  It was able to create the backup folder.  But, it said it was unable to move the .anaconda folder.  Then, it just crashed.  I also tried running the command shell as admin and it failed again.  I don't suppose there is a way to get it to continue to run since i don't care if the backup succeeds.

Comment: I also listed the environments.  I saw that only the base one exists and it doesn't contain karas - even though there is a keras folder at the root of my user folder.  Is there a way to get anaconda to discover existing environment?

Comment: Did you get an error code? If you tell me what you got I can check myself but look here for other errors - https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/user-guide/troubleshooting/

Comment: Other Ideas, try just running Uninstall-Anaconda.exe in the install directory

Comment: The error message just said that it could not move the .anaconda folder.  I didn't see an error code.  So, I did a search and found the source code for anaconda-clean.  After reading through it, I found the list of folders that anaconda-clear looks for and deleted them manually.